# I am trying to exclude sonar scans on the file

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonatype

I have set this up in Pom.xml file to exclude the sonar scans but it's not working. Are there any syntax issues?

Can anyone help in fixing this?

```
<sonar.exclusions >**/src/main/**/lib/angular/**,**/Src/main/**/js/*</sonar.exclusions>
```

Answer (score 0):

- There is a space between `exclusions` and closing `>` in your exemple. Remove it.
- you should put a space after the argument separating comma
- your second argument mentions a `**S**rc` that is most probably `**s**rc`in a Maven context

Comment: Hey though I edited the space at > , src * and space after first argument it still not excluding the code in that directory

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do.

```
        <sonar.exclusions>
            src/main/java/com/bean/**,
            src/main/java/com/response/**,
            src/main/java/com/filter/**,
            src/main/java/com/constants/**
        </sonar.exclusions>
```